# Getting Invalid Hook Error in React App after trying to wrap app in provider

Tags: reactjs

I am building a mock e-commerce store using react and after laying the groundwork for the website, I installed the package react-use-cart (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-cart) to handle the items being added to the cart and to be used in a checkout page. I wrapped my app in the Cart Provider that was given by the react-use-cart package and set up the cart functions on my product pages but now my app does not load anything on startup and gives me an invalid hook call error. I have tried wrapping the app in the index.js file with the provider as well and that gives the same error.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './css/App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar"
import ProductsScreen from "./screens/ProductsScreen"
import ProductDetailScreen from "./screens/ProductDetailScreen"
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen"
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen"
import RegisterScreen from "./screens/RegisterScreen";
import CartScreen from "./screens/CartScreen"
import { CartProvider } from "react-use-cart";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <CartProvider>
        <NavBar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen/>}/>
            <Route path='/products' element={<ProductsScreen/>}/>
            <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductDetailScreen/>}/>
            <Route path='/login' element={<LoginScreen/>}/>
            <Route path='/register' element={<RegisterScreen/>}/>
            <Route path='/cart' element={<CartScreen/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </CartProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

[image]

```
import { useState, useEffect }from 'react'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import "../css/ProductDetailScreen.css"
import { useCart } from "react-use-cart";
// import Slideshow from '../components/SlideShow'

const { addItem, updateItemQuantity } = useCart();
const ProductDetailScreen = ( {match} ) => {

    const [product, setProduct] = useState({})
    const { id } = useParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        const getProduct = async () => {
          const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
          setProduct(data)
        }
    
        getProduct()
      }, [])

    return (
    <>  
        <Link to ='/products'>Go Back</Link>
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="detail-grid">
                <div className='imgContainer'> 
                    <img className='cover_img1' src={product.cover_img} alt='Videogame Cover Art'/>
                    <div className='carousel'>
                        {product.images?.map((image, index) => (
                            <img key={index} src={image} alt="Videogame Gameplay"></img>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    {/*Replace carousel div with actual image slideshow*/}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className='textContainer'>
                        <h1 className='title1'>{product.title}</h1>
                        <h3 className='descriptionHeader'>Description:</h3>
                        <p className='description1'>{product.description}</p>
                        <h3 className='developer1'>Developer: {product.developer}</h3>
                        <h3 className='publisher1'>Publisher: {product.publisher}</h3>
                        <h3 className='releaseDate1'>Release Date: {product.releaseDate}</h3>
                        <h3 className='genre1'>Genre: {product.genre}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className='checkOutContainer'>
                        <h3 className='price1'>Price: ${product.price}</h3>
                        <button onClick={() => updateItemQuantity(product.id, product.quantity - 1)}> - </button>
                        <span>{product.quantity}</span>
                        <button onClick={() => updateItemQuantity(product.id, product.quantity + 1)}> + </button>
                        <button onClick={() => addItem(product)} className='addCart' type='button'>Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
    )
}

export default ProductDetailScreen
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the error that you get?

Comment: Added error image

Comment: Can you post the code of the PoroductDetailScreen.js, I mean the code part where useCart is being used.

Comment: Added the productdetailscreen.js code

Comment: You have to move the useCart part inside the ProductDetailScreen function. Currently you are using it outside the ProductDetailScreen function right.

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe I missed that @DulajAriyaratne